# Тэг <use/> не работает в data:image/svg+xml,<svg

Tags: css, svg

Я хотел добавить .svg в мою .htm страницу. Но 'use' не работает в 'svg' при вставке с data:image. Как это сделать?

```
background:url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='180' height='118' 
fill='white'><path d='M90,14 143,108H37z' stroke-width='11' 
stroke='red'/><g id='cr'><path d='M70,68 73,59H90L93,68' stroke-width='2' 
stroke='black'/><path d='M67,70H93V74H67M71,74V81M92,74V81' stroke-
width='5' stroke='black'/></g><use x='13' y='8' xlink:href='#cr'/><use 
x='26' y='16' xlink:href='#cr'/></svg>")
```

Comment: используйте base64

Comment: Пробовал добавить ,base64 -не помогает. base64 для .svg не особо и нужен. всё без него прекрасно работает.

Comment: какая-то ошибка даже конвертер в ai не хочет работать

Comment: Возможно, вы намудрили с пробелами: https://jsfiddle.net/br3t/f3j8f3qc/

Comment: br3t: С какими пробелами? С пробелами в <svg></svg>? Всё дело в двух тегах <use/>, если оба удалить то отображается та часть картинки за которую тэги не отвечают. Просто мне кажется что сам форомат .svg еще "сырой и зелёный". В будещем возможно он получит более широкое распостранение, когда вэб-строй община поймёт сколько плюсов и выгоды этот формат . svg имеет.

Comment: @Alexander V. Ulyanov давайте разберемся по порядку. Вы задали вопрос почему use не работает и спросили, как это сделать? Я подробно объяснил причины и указал другие рабочие способы решения вашей проблемы. В моем примере всё работает, берите и пользуйтесь на здоровье.

Comment: @Alexandr_T что не понятного я написал внизу? Ок, повторю: "Я уже писал об этом ещё в апреле. Смотрите выше, там об этом мной уже написано было. Удалите пожалуйста ваш ответ, если не трудно." Я в апреле: "Всё дело в двух тегах <use/>, если оба удалить то отображается та часть картинки за которую тэги не отвечают."

Answer (score 3):

Вы правильно заметили, что `<use>` не работает, когда svg код добавляют в Html в качестве `background`.
USE это очень своеобразная команда. Как только вы её задействовали, элемент сразу попадает в shadow DOM. И возникает определенное количество проблем, со стилизацией например.

Для проверки убрал use из вашего примера - всё работает

```css
#car {
width:200px;
height:200px;
 background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="200"> <path d="M90,14 143,108H37z" stroke-width="11" stroke="red" fill="none"/><g id="cr"><path d="M70,68 73,59H90L93,68" stroke-width="2" stroke="black" fill="none"/><path d="M67,70H93V74H67M71,74V81M92,74V81" stroke-width="5" stroke="black" fill="1none"/></g> </svg>');
}
```

```html
<div id="car"></div>
```

Для использования use необходимо использовать другие способы добавления кода SVG в Html: например инлайн, когда код svg непосредственно встраивается в веб страницу. Подробнее о других способах встраивания SVG -- [тут](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047).

Ниже пример инлайн добавления кода svg c работающим use:

```html
<style>
#car {
width:200px;
height:118px;
}
</style>
<div id="car">
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="118"> 
<path d="M90,14 143,108H37z" stroke-width="11" stroke="red" fill="none"/>
<g id="cr">
<path d="M70,68 73,59H90L93,68" stroke-width="2" stroke="black" fill="none"/>
<path d="M67,70H93V74H67M71,74V81M92,74V81" stroke-width="5" stroke="black" fill="1none"/>
</g>
<use x="13" y="8" xlink:href="#cr"/>
<use x="26" y="16" xlink:href="#cr"/> 
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Я уже писал об этом ещё в апреле. Смотрите выше, там об этом мной уже написано было. Удалите пожалуйста ваш ответ, если не трудно.